# gmail shows text as links while it shouldnt

Tags: gmail, html-email, newsletter, email-templates

Does anybody know if there is a special trick to make gmail not to show text as an htmllink?
We are sending newsletters to our customers, and there is a possibility that in the text is something like "one-company.com inc." and gmail makes a link.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: thats not an option @DaniSpringer

Comment: Edited. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done.
you need to enclose all Dots (.) and at-the-rate-of '@' symbols in < span>< / span> blocks.
i.e x@y.com should become x< span>@< / span>y< span>.< span>com

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like this also. Here trick is ancher tag without href.

```
  '<a style="text-                                       
   decoration:none;color:yourchoice">your text whatever it may be</      
   a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Img

Make an image. Of course, not hyperlinked.

## Option 2: !important, inline

Add `!important` to your **inline** styles (`<head>` styles are *ignored* in Gmail)

Answer (score -1):

I doubt, if you have control over it. It probably depends on the end-users gmail settings and by default gmail converts something like one-company.com to a link, unless the user has turned this feature off in gmail.

Comment: There is no such setting. Gmail always converts text to links when finding them.

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
one-company&#046;com
```

`&#046;` is the ascii character for period

if that doesn't work, create a small image for the period and sandwich that in there.